# How do I cause a browser redirect from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm creating a gem and I was wondering how I can add a browser redirect. For example, if a class method from the gem is called in a Rails controller, the browser will redirect to a new url.

I can only seem to launch a URL in a new tab/window. In Rails I would call a simple `redirect_to` but I'm not sure of how to do this in Ruby alone.

Comment: So this is *not* a Rails question? What are you using to communicate with the browser? Sinatra? CGI? Some other framework?

Comment: Well, this is a gem that would be included in a Rails project.